# Negation in /src="http/':"src=\"{$pageUrl}

Tags: php, regex, smarty, regex-negation

Regular Expressions in smarty.
I need to find and replace all different from

```
src = "http://
```

I'm trying to use the function

```
regex_replace:'/src="http/':"src=\"{$pageUrl}"
```

Is there any sign of the negation text?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need negative lookahead:

```
regex_replace:"/src=\"(?!http:\/\/).*?\"/":"src=\"{$pageUrl}\""
```